# Okta SAML SLO request AuthnFailed/Invalid Signature

Tags: php, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to perform an SP initiated SAML 2.0 SLO in PHP, my problem: LogoutResponse status code AuthnFailed, hence no IdP logout. According to the Okta (IdP) dashboard the reason is Invalid Signature.
I am using robrichards/xmlseclibs security lib and POST binding. The request validates on https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php and through http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php.

Here's my beautified request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<samlp:LogoutRequest
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    ID="_logout_1_5ab86804b6057"
    Version="2.0"
    Destination="https://dev-680804.oktapreview.com/app/catalystitdev680000_xxxx_1/exkeb8o4nbMQ7xxxxxxx/slo/saml"
    IssueInstant="2018-03-26T16:24:52+13:00">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://xxxxxxx/</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference>
                <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>5SXEPj5gyXWuf/BXfZ7QTVrUuJaF3Khh...</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>TmAUPHY4rO...</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIFUzCCAzugAwIBAgI...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">and...</saml:NameID>
    <samlp:SessionIndex>_authn_5ab8680105723</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

This is how I created my pkey and crt:

```
#!/bin/bash

# https://github.com/mattermost/docs/blob/master/source/scripts/generate-certificates/gencert.md

umask 377

certname="${CRT_FILENAME:-"nzta-x509"}"
openssl x509 \
    -in <(
        openssl req \
            -days 3650 \
            -newkey rsa:4096 \
            -nodes \
            -keyout "${certname}.key" \
            -subj "/C=${CRT_C:-"NZ"}/L=${CRT_L:-"Wellington"}/O=${CRT_O:-"XXXX"}/OU=${CRT_OU:-"Sysadmins"}/CN=${CRT_CN:-"xxxx-xxxx"}"
        ) \
    -req \
    -signkey "${certname}.key" \
    -sha256 \
    -days 3650 \
    -out "${certname}.crt" \
    -extfile <(echo -e "basicConstraints=critical,CA:true,pathlen:0")

chmod 600 ${certname}.crt
```

I am running out of ideas. How can I get more error context. "Invalid Signature" doesn't help me much...

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid Signature" means the LogoutRequest is not signed properly. Typical problems would be:

1. Signature Hashing Algorithm. Check what Signature Hashing Algorithm (eg: SHA256 or MD5) configured for your partner in IdP, you need to use the same to sign your message.
2. Incorrect private key used to sign the message. Check whether correct public-private key pair is used and associated certificate is configured at IdP and same certificate is sending via LogoutRequest.
3. Check whether the whole LogoutRequest message is signed and not just few elements of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zeitgeist. I found a good tool for doing that:

```
xmlsec1 --verify LogoutRequest.xml
```

The output is quite verbose, giving me a lot to chew through:

```
func=xmlSecOpenSSLX509StoreVerify:file=x509vfy.c:line=360:obj=x509-store:subj=X509_verify_cert:error=4:crypto library function failed:subj=/C=NZ/L=Wellington/O=XXX/OU=Sysadmins/CN=xxx-xxx;err=18;msg=self signed certificate
func=xmlSecOpenSSLX509StoreVerify:file=x509vfy.c:line=408:obj=x509-store:subj=unknown:error=71:certificate verification failed:err=18;msg=self signed certificate
func=xmlSecKeysMngrGetKey:file=keys.c:line=1370:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecKeysMngrFindKey:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=871:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=45:key is not found: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessSignatureNode:file=xmldsig.c:line=565:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecDSigCtxProcessKeyInfoNode:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
func=xmlSecDSigCtxVerify:file=xmldsig.c:line=366:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecDSigCtxSignatureProcessNode:error=1:xmlsec library function failed: 
Error: signature failed 
ERROR
SignedInfo References (ok/all): 1/1
Manifests References (ok/all): 0/0
Error: failed to verify file "LogoutRequest.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the transmitted  ds:X509Certificate  text content with what is configured on IDP side.  I discovered the transmitted version includes newline and whites pace chars  which will fail in a string match.  I removed them and it validated.

Late reply but hope this helps someone